# Fastlane deliver ignoring increment_version_number (using xcode settings version)

Tags: ios, xcode, devops, fastlane, fastlane-deliver

For some reason fastlane deliver has started using the marketing version defined in our .xcodeproj file instead of the version we dynamically pass in during the pipeline run.

I can see the correct version is being set/referenced during the run at various points:

```
[16:34:28]: $ cd /Users/****/appname && agvtool new-marketing-version 2.11.1
[16:34:28]: ▸ Setting CFBundleShortVersionString of project appname to:
[16:34:28]: ▸ 2.11.1.
[16:34:28]: ▸ Updating CFBundleShortVersionString in Info.plist(s)...
[16:34:28]: ▸ Updated CFBundleShortVersionString in "appname.xcodeproj/../Info.plist" to 2.11.1
```

Further down at the deliver stage for some reason app_version is 9.9.9

```
+--------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
|                         deliver 2.207.0 Summary                          |
+--------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| ipa                                  | ./build/appname.ipa         |
| precheck_include_in_app_purchases    | false                             |
| submit_for_review                    | false                             |
| force                                | true                              |
| metadata_path                        | .fastlane/metadata                |
| api_key                              | ********                          |
| screenshots_path                     | ./.fastlane/screenshots           |
| app_version                          | 9.9.9
```

Lane context on error - trying to upload existing (and incorrect) 9.9.9 version

```
| LATEST_TESTFLIGHT_VERSION          | 2.11.1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       |
| BUILD_NUMBER                       | 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |
| VERSION_NUMBER                     | 2.11.1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       |
| IPA_OUTPUT_PATH                    | /Users/****/build/appname.ipa                                                                                                                                                                                      |
| XCODEBUILD_ARCHIVE                 | ./archive/appname2022-07-12 16.35.38.xcarchive                                                                                                                                                                                        |
                                                                                                                                                                        |
+------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
[16:42:44]: Error uploading ipa file: 
 [Transporter Error Output]: ERROR ITMS-90189: Redundant Binary Upload. You've already uploaded a build with build number '1' for version number '9.9.9'.
```

We've updated the build machine to xcode 13.4.1 from 13.1 and disabled bitcode but not changed anything in fastlane around versioning.

We've also gone up a minor version 2.10.x to 2.11.x - I doubt any of these things could cause this?

Appreciate any ideas or configuration to check

fastlane lane:

```
  increment_build_number_from_appstore(
      app_version: options[:app_version],
      asc_key_id: options[:asc_key_id],
      asc_issuer_id: options[:asc_issuer_id],
      asc_key: options[:asc_key])
  increment_version_number(
      version_number: options[:app_version],
      xcodeproj: @xcode_project)
  build_app(
      scheme: @scheme,
      export_method: "app-store",
      export_options: {
         provisioningProfiles: {
           "com.xxxxx" => "match AppStore com.xxxxx
         }
      },
      configuration: "Release",
      include_symbols: true,
      project: @xcode_project,
      build_path: @archive_directory,
      output_directory: @output_directory,
      cloned_source_packages_path: options[:cloned_source_packages_path],
      output_name: "appname")
  deliver(
      ipa: @ipa,
      precheck_include_in_app_purchases: false,
      submit_for_review: false,
      force: true,
      metadata_path: ".fastlane/metadata")
```

Update: reverting to Xcode 13.1 and the versioning is fine again - do we need to configure something on the build machine or sounds like a bug?